# I think I have a problem with pyenv on my server

Tags: python, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I have used pyenv to create some virtualenv for my project, and a few month ago, it seems to make some confusing problem.

Everytime when I go into the directory which I had set venv, it looks work, but it won't work currectly

```
root@VM-4-7-debian:~# cd /www/wwwroot/FFXIVBOT
(venv-ffxivbot) root@VM-4-7-debian:/www/wwwroot/FFXIVBOT# pyenv versions
  system
  3.8.9
  3.8.9/envs/venv-ffxivbot
  3.8.9/envs/venv-maibot
  3.8.9/envs/venv-telegram
  3.8.9/envs/venv-temp
  3.9.12
* venv-ffxivbot (set by /www/wwwroot/FFXIVBOT/.python-version)
  venv-maibot
  venv-telegram
  venv-temp
(venv-ffxivbot) root@VM-4-7-debian:/www/wwwroot/FFXIVBOT# python --version
Python 2.7.16
(venv-ffxivbot) root@VM-4-7-debian:/www/wwwroot/FFXIVBOT# ~/.pyenv/versions/venv-ffxivbot/bin/python --version
Python 3.8.9
(venv-ffxivbot) root@VM-4-7-debian:/www/wwwroot/FFXIVBOT#
```

here is the settings in my `.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="/www/server/nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:~/go/bin"


export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "

export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"alias php='php -c /www/server/php/74/etc/php-cli.ini'
alias php74='php74 -c /www/server/php/74/etc/php-cli.ini'
```

I really don't know why it will happen.

my PATH:

```
root@VM-4-7-debian:~# echo $PATH
/root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:~/.pyenv/bin:/www/server/nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:~/go/bin
root@VM-4-7-debian:~#
```

Comment: .bashrc is not running on cd

Comment: what os do you run? read https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#understanding-path i thnk its a path problem

can you print out your path?

echo "$PATH"

Comment: @flaxon here is my path `/root/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:~/.pyenv/bin:/www/server/nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:~/go/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I have just repair it when I try to replace
`eval "$(pyenv init -)"`
into
`eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`
in my `.bashrc`.

I think it because pyenv had change the command which will be wrote in `.bashrc`.

pyenv has said these two different settings to be wrote into `.bashrc` on his [README](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/blob/master/README.rst) and now `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` might be the wrong one.